# Error occur while using Dbquery entity framwork for displaying the data between two relational DB_tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use DbQuery do display data between two relational tables which are Agent and Device tables.

I am using Dbquery for fetching the data from the two tables then display them for viewing only, but I am facing this Exceptional error

> invalid object name 'AgentDevice'

Error is occurs within SearchAsync method

```
public async Task<ReturnResult<PagedResult<AgentDevice>>> SearchAsync( int? IsActive = null, string SearchString = "", int PageNumber = 1, int PageSize = 10)
{
    try
    {
        **the error is showing in this line**
        var DeviceAgent = await db.DeviceAgent.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToListAsync();
        result.Success(DeviceAgent);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message, result);
        result.ServerError(ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

```
public class AgentDevice
{
    public long? AgentId { get; set; }
    public long? DeviceId { get; set; }
    public long? DeviceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

// this is Device Table exists in Database
public class Device
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public long? DeviceTypeId { get; set; }
    public long? AgentId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public Agent Agent { get; set; }
}

// this Agent table exists in Database
public class Agent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
//here is the dbconext class 
public class EweAttendanceDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
{
    public EweAttendanceDbContext()
    {
            
    }
    public EweAttendanceDbContext(DbContextOptions<EweAttendanceDbContext> options)
        : base(options)  {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Agent> Agent { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Device> Device { get; set; }
    public DbQuery<AgentDevice> AgentDevice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbquery-1?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/59427708/ef-core-3-dbquery-equivalent-functionality

Answer (score 0):

Create a view in db with name "AgentDevice". DbQuery looks for view AgentDevice which is missing in your db